# How to sort the result of wp_query

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, wordpress

I'm trying to sort the results of wp_query, i want to sort it by different parameters without make the query again. I have something like that:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And i want to sort $the_query, WP_Query returns a structure like that:

```
$the_query->posts[0]->title;
```

So, I want to sort all the elements by 'title' for example. I tried this:

```
usort($the_query->posts, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['title'] - $b['title'];
});
```

I want to sort after i do the query. Is because i want tosort many times and i dont want to do the query every time i want to sort

SOLUTION

This returns Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array

```
usort($the_query->posts, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['title'] - $b['title'];
});
```

This is because the structure of the array is like that:

```
$the_query->posts[0]->title;
```

so you have to change `$a['title'] - $b['title']`  for `$a->title - $b->title`
and using the answer of Pieter Goosen the Final result is:

```
usort($the_query->posts, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp( 
            $a->title, 
            $b->title
        );
});
```

Thank for all

Comment: +1 for the excellent clean format of your question :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at the `orderby` and `order` parameters in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). If you need to sort by post title, you can add the following to your query parameters

```
'orderby' => 'title'
'order' => 'ASC'
```

**EDIT**

If you need to sort with `usort`, you can do the following

```
usort($the_query->posts, function($a, $b) {
   return strcasecmp( 
                $a->post_title, 
                $b->post_title 
            );
});
```

Comment: That works but i want to sort after i do the query, i mean i have $query = new WP_Query($args) i want to sort $query. Is because i want to do that many times and i dont want to do the query every time i want to sort

Comment: it returns Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array

Comment: Cool, that's the solution I've gotten

Answer (score 1):

WP_Query('orderby=date&order=DESC')

Or try this, if you want to sort based on custom meta value.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_key' => 'pb_issue_featured',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'paged' => 1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'headline',
                'value' => 1,
                'compare' => '!=' 
                )
            )
        );

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_query' );
$q = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_query' );

function filter_query( $query ) {
    $query .= ', wp_posts.menu_order ASC';
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Your answer have no relevance to the question. Also, why are you even using a custom filter to sort when you have that build in functionality already

Comment: Ok, i understand that, but i want sort after i do the query, i mean i have  $query = new WP_Query($args)  i want to sort $query. Is because i want to do that many times and i dont want to do the query every time i want to sort with "x" param