# How to sort the columns of my query in WordPress

Tags: sql, wordpress

hello thanks to the query here below I manage to display various information from my wordpress database it works very well

But now I would like each column to be able to be sorted ascending and descending when the user clicks on the column title, is this possible?

```
<?php 
    // Example for adding WP PageNavi to a new WP_Query call
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    // les 5 dernieres journees de peche
    // 1. On définit les arguments pour définir ce que l'on souhaite récupérer    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'category_name' => 'nouveautes',
              'paged' => $paged
    );
  
    
    ?>

     <div >
        <div >Detail</div>
        <div >Date</div>
        <div >Nbre de prise</div>
        <div >Membre</div>

      </div>
    <?php   
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();  
        
        $total_des_prises = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'total_des_prises', true );?>
        <?php $variable=get_the_title();?>
        <?php //echo  get_the_author_meta ; ?>
         <div style=' display: flex;border:3px solid #8ebf42;'>
    
<div ><?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . 'Détail' . '</a>';?></div>
        <div ><?php echo  get_the_date() ; ?></div>
        <div ><?php  echo  $total_des_prises ;?></div>
        <div ><?php echo  get_the_author() ;?></div>

        
      </div>
        <?php
  

     }
        
        wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $the_query ) );
    }
    
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort the result of wp\_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943392/how-to-sort-the-result-of-wp-query)

Comment: thanks for the link i'm looking at that